# How to ignore packets that doesn't have a valid OpCode

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, tcpclient

So I'm currently learning about networking in terms of the relationship between a server and it's clients. And as far as I understand, the server starts listening for incoming connections and once a connection has been established, packets will be sent back and forth.

Here is my take on it, I like to visualize it in a way of how a game would do it.

So you have your server running and then you connect with your client, with the connection comes a `Login` packet, the server would then parse this packet and continue the login process and the client would eventually login to the game world.

Packets are structured in a certain way to easily keep track of what type of packet it is by using an OpCode, the length of the packet and the actual payload.

So something like this.. `[OpCode(2bytes), Length(4bytes), Payload(xBytes)]`
And the server would then expect this format.

**Issue**

What if there was a malicious user who were to send a packet that doesn't match that packet format? I would have to dump that entire packet that the malicious user sent, but I don't know how big it is so I don't know how much to dump, leaving me at a spot prone for server crashes.

**Question**

How do I dump/ignore a packet that doesn't have a valid OpCode.. A Valid OpCode is an OpCode that exists in the `OpCode` enum

```
enum OpCode : short
{
    Connect = 0
}
```

The way I'm doing it now is that I start the server by initializing the packets

```
Packets = new Dictionary<OpCode, IPacket>();
Packets.Add(OpCode.Connect, new ConnectPacket());
```

and calling a method named `Run`

```
public void Run()
{
    _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Constants.PORT);
    _listener.Start(10);
    _isRunning = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Server has started..");
    
    while (_isRunning)
    {
        _clients.Add(new Connection(_listener.AcceptTcpClient(), Packets));
    }
}
```

When a TcpClient has been accepted, it enters the constructor

```
private TcpClient _socket;
private Dictionary<OpCode, IPacket> _packets;
public NetReader Reader;

public Connection(TcpClient client, Dictionary<OpCode, IPacket> packets)
{
    _buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    _socket = client;
    _packets = packets;
    
    Reader = new NetReader(_socket.GetStream());
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Client connected: {_socket.Client.RemoteEndPoint}");
    ProcessPackets();
}
```

And as you can see I call the `ProcessPackets` function which checks if the first two bytes evaluates to a valid OpCode, if so, process the rest of the data that follows, if not I guess I want to dump the data and read the next packet.
Same goes for if the malicious packet somehow gets the OpCode right, if that's the case then dump the packet because the rest of the packet will probably be corrupt.

```
public void ProcessPackets()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        IPacket packet;
        while (true)
        {
            OpCode = Reader.ReadInt16();
            if (_packets.TryGetValue((OpCode)OpCode, out packet))
            {
                _packets[(OpCode)OpCode].Process(this);
            }
            else
            {
                //Dump the packet
                
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And here is an example of what a `Process` function could look like, but it doesn't matter that much since I want to solve dumping the packet if the OpCode isn't valid first.

```
public void Process(Connection connection)
{
    var length = connection.Reader.ReadInt32();
    var payload = connection.Reader.ReadBytes(length);
    Console.WriteLine($"Received and processed Connection Packet");
}
```

NetReader is just a class that derives from `BinaryReader`

```
class NetReader : BinaryReader
{
    private NetworkStream _ns;
    private byte[] _tempBuffer;
    public NetReader(NetworkStream ns) : base(ns)
    {
        _ns = ns;
        _tempBuffer = new byte[8];
    }
    public override byte ReadByte()
    {
        byte val = (byte)_ns.ReadByte();
        return val;
    }
    public override short ReadInt16()
    {
        int val = _ns.Read(_tempBuffer, 0, 2);
        return BitConverter.ToInt16(_tempBuffer, 0)
    }
    public override int ReadInt32()
    {
        int val = _ns.Read(_tempBuffer, 0, 4);  
        return BitConverter.ToInt32(_tempBuffer, 0)
    }
    public override byte[] ReadBytes(int count)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[count];
        _ns.Read(bytes, 0, count);
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of text here but it's unclear what your question is.

Comment: The question is based on the title as well as what follows the **Issue** part, I had to explain the issue in order for it to make sense and so that there is enough information, is there anything I can do to make it more clear? If so I'll change it up a bit.

Comment: Your requirements may differ, but I would consider any such invalid data as evidence of malicious intent and close the entire connection, not merely drop the packet. You should also log enough information to 1) permit some detailed analysis should such problems persist, and 2) identify any bugs in the client or server in case that's the real problem.

Comment: That's what I was leaning towards, dropping the client connection. Good points, I'll keep that in mind!